# check string format and numbers only

Tags: c#

I have this to check digits:

```
 private bool IsDigitsOnly(string str)
    {
        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This to check string len

```
 private bool CorrectFormat(string str)
    {
        if (str.Length == 9)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

I use this on property SET

```
 public string NIF
    {
        get { return nif; }
        set { if (IsDigitsOnly(nif) && CorrectFormat(nif))
                nif = value;
        }
```

But when I try to make an object instance I got an error
      "System null reference exception" when I am using 123456789 in parameter that is always true when checked by two methods before.

Some help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use `value` instead of `nif` in the property setter:

```
public string NIF
{
    get { return nif; }
    set { if (IsDigitsOnly(value) && CorrectFormat(value))
            nif = value;
    }
}
```

You're going to assign the `value` to the  backing field `nif` *after* the checks.

Comment: Perfect! Thank's a lot!